# GettingWindows 8 system information programmatically

Tags: windows-8

How to get System model /system type information programmatically using C# in Windows 8 application?

Answer (score 2):

The [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724340.aspx) function is allowed API in store apps. Just use [PInvoke as usual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) and you'll have all information in a [SYSTEM_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724958.aspx) struct.

Comment: Hi I am using C# code and not C++ API, Please tell me how to get it via C# code

Comment: As I mentioned, you'll have to use PInvoke to call the C-function from C#.

Comment: i need to take the following information - DeviceName, DeviceUniqueId, DeviceManufacturer, DeviceFirmwareVersion,DeviceHardwareVersion, DeviceTotalMemory, ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage, is that  possible in windows 8 ?

Comment: I don't think so. Something akin to DeviceUniqueId is available via HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx